# Difference between pixel based and frame based methods

Tags: c++, opencv, frame, pixel, gaussian

I am working on video frames using OpenCV. My question might be low leveled, but I want to clarify it first.

There are plenty of pixel based methods available in openCV, but can I change them into frame based ones?

To me, it is similar, since the whole frame is also stored in one matrix, and I will read that matrix from the beginning to end to handle it. So for instance for finding average value, the only thing I should change is find the total average of whole pixels for one frame.

But for one pixel, see several frames and decide that pixel's average based on them. But when it comes to build models like GMM, I cannot differentiate it.

Could someone help explain it clearly?

Can I use or change openCV's GMM for global usage?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. I understand that pixel based is when you process pixels in image separately. But also for a global process of the frame yoy have to access the pixels, so it is pixel baxel based too in the end. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: yes, that is also what I am thinking of. But I am arguing with my friend about it, he told me frame based should be different, but he doesn't tell how. I said even in frame based ones, we have to access each single pixels so there should not be difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a good definition for the problem, though you are working with pixels.

- **Pixel-based methods**: The information of the pixel(x,y) in the resulting processed image is the result of applying transformations to the pixel(x,y) of the original image.
- **Region-based methods**: The pixels in the original image are grouped forming a contiguous regions and transformations are applied to the whole region. Example: the resulting pixel(x,y) is the mean of a patch around the original pixel (x,y).